# Redirect to another page after submitting form

Tags: 2013, redirect, datasheet

I have a sharepoint 2013 list. When the user clicks on edit this list to open it in  a datasheet view...after making changes when clicked on **stop** ,the data should be saved and redirect to another page. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can it be redirected from the datasheet view?

Comment: Only when you hook into Microsofts events with Javascript (somehow)

Comment: I have tried to redirect it based on the url..but after clicking stop editing this list..the page is not loaded again

Answer (score 2):

This is without using jquery

Create a custom new list form.

Remove/Comment the save button and add new save button instead

```
<input type="button" class="Add-button" value="Save" name="btnSave" onclick="if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;{ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={/SiteAssets/Thank%20You.aspx}')}"
```

In `PreSaveItem()` , you can write your validation code if required!

Comment: Can it be redirected from the datasheet view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script to redirect to another page after submitting the form. you can use any jquery reference.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {

var button = $("input[id$=SaveItem]");
// change redirection behavior
    button.removeAttr("onclick");
    button.click(function() {
        var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
        var aspForm = $("form[name=aspnetForm]");
        var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action;
        var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
        var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, "MyRedirectionDestination.aspx");

        if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
        WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
    });

});
```

Comment: Can it be redirected from the datasheet view?