# Redirect from list to another list when users click submit button

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

I have two separate lists in SharePoint 2010 customized by info path. How to redirect from one list to another list form when users click submit button from List "A".

NB:

Users filled up List form "A" and click submit button, the item is going to save and redirect to another button.

Answer (score 0):

There are some methods to achieve your requirement:

1. Use source URL

   `http://<site>/list1/Forms/NewItem.aspx?Source=http://<site>/list2/Forms/NewItem.aspx`

to redirect to another page when this form closed.

2. Add new submit button and use code to redirect.
3. Use JQuery script to redirect to another form page after submitting the form.

Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/212368/redirect-to-another-page-after-submitting-form) similar post.