# Parent/Child List: go back to Modal Parent dispform after child form submit/save

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, list-form, modal-dialog

My need is very close to something already treated like [this topic](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/212368/redirect-to-another-page-after-submitting-form)
but the solutions doesn not seems to work on Modal/Dialog forms.

In my context, I have a parent list ("projects") and a child list ("milestones").
On my parent dispform, I display too the child´s new form. Both are displayed as dialogs, not on a new page.

My issue, is that when from teh parent dispform, i add new child. And when I save the new child item, I want to go back to the parent dispform but in dialog mode.

I have a [script](http://www.sharepointhillbilly.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=26) that pass the parent ID to the child list by overwritting the "new item" child link. I tried adding &Source="http...." with the url of the parent dispform but without success.
**Maybe I am not finding the correct url to the modal parent dispform?**
I also tried overwritting the "save" button in the child newform but without success either.

In pictures:
Where I start, my project list: i want to add multiple milestones
[image]
After clicking "add new milestones", the child new form arrive
[image]
And when I save my new milestone, I go back to
[image]
instead of going back to the **previous** modal dispform
[image]

I also have a second problem: on teh parent dispform, if in the area displaying the child new form, I choose "edit", to bulk edit. When I click "stop editing", I got an error message...and I have no clue where to look at to find the issue.
[image]

Thnaks for reading this far, any help will be appreciated.